# Can't run Ansible playbook against EC2 host

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm trying to run a simple Ansible playbook against an already-provisioned EC2 host. When I run ansible-playbook, I get the following error:

```
SSH Error: data could not be sent to the remote host. Make sure this host can be reached over ssh
```

Using the Amazon-supplied .pem file, I can manually ssh into the box just fine by just doing

> ssh ubuntu@my_instance_ip

.

This is the full command I'm running:

```
ansible-playbook --inventory-file=inventory/production --extra-vars=ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu my-playbook.yml -vvvv
```

This is my inventory file (IP/DNS masked):

```
[test]
ec2-1-1-1-1.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com   ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/path_to_pem_file.pem
```

The interesting thing is if I run the ssh command that the ansible-playbook verbosely spits out:

```
ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60m -o ControlPath="/Users/me/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o IdentityFile="/path_to_my_pem_file.pem" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ubuntu -o ConnectTimeout=10 ec2-1-1-1-1.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I get the following:

```
debug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path /Users/me/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-ec2-1-1-1-1.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com-22-ubuntu.8MjEBnDdRIAO8zAT
unix_listener: "/Users/me/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-ec2-1-1-1-1.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com-22-ubuntu.8MjEBnDdRIAO8zAT" too long for Unix domain socket
```

Is that error valid? If so, is there anyway to make the command shorter? Thanks!

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970686/ansible-ssh-error-unix-listener-too-long-for-unix-domain-socket

Comment: Yup, that was it! Not sure how I missed that. I set the control_path config to something shorter and it worked.

Comment: As knowhy pointed out, the problem/answer are located here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970686/ansible-ssh-error-unix-listener-too-long-for-unix-domain-socket

Comment: It's a super rare constraint people usually only hit against aws machine. I wonder why you didn't get the `too long for Unix domain socket` error in verbose mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments and in the [linked SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970686/ansible-ssh-error-unix-listener-too-long-for-unix-domain-socket) the relevant error message here is: `too long for Unix domain socket`. This error can be solved by tweaking the `control_path` parameter in `ansible.cfg`

> The path to use for the ControlPath sockets. This defaults to
>   "%(directory)s/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r", however on some systems with
>   very long hostnames or very long path names (caused by long user names or 
>   deeply nested home directories) this can exceed the character limit on
>   file socket names (108 characters for most platforms). In that case, you 
>   may wish to shorten the string below.
>
> Example: 
>   control_path = %(directory)s/%%h-%%r

Answer (score 1):

I have twice the problem as machines are domain joined and the `$HOME` path is very long and so is my username, eg: `/home/local.companyname.com/Smitty.Werbenjagermanjensen` so virtually any control socket path is going to be too damned long.

There are two other ways to go about addressing this problem:

1. For long hostnames:

   - Instead of using the usual flags `%r`, `%h`, and `%p` you can use `%C` which is a hash of the three.
   - eg: `dfd609b4ea05eab3927aa71b91115b29317d017d`
   - **Note:** This option is apparently a recent addition to ssh, so if it's not working you really should look at updating ssh and/or your OS.
2. For long preceding paths:

   - I very much prefer my sockets live in `~/.ssh/sockets` so that no one else can touch them.

     ```
     mkdir -p ~/.ssh/sockets && \
     chmod 0700 ~/.ssh/sockets && \
     sudo ln -s ~/.ssh/sockets /var/local/sw-ssh && \
     sudo chown -h $myuser:$mydomain /var/local/sw-ssh
     ```
   - Set your Ansible `control_path` to `/var/local/sw-ssh/%%C`

With both of these my socket paths go from: `/home/local.companyname.com/Smitty.Werbenjagermanjensen/.ssh/sockets/Smitty.Werbenjagermanjensen@foobar.dev.application.companyname.com-22`

To: `/var/local/sw-ssh/dfd609b4ea05eab3927aa71b91115b29317d017d`

**Note:** This is all perfectly valid ssh client config and can be added to your `~/.ssh/config` instead so you can benefit from ssh sockety goodness 24/7 and not just while you're running Ansible plays.

```
Host *
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath /var/local/sw-ssh/%C
    ControlPersist 600
```